# [elasticsearch]documents that have been deleted can be searched again after es cluster restart

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have a es cluster deployed in k8s which consists of three nodes, and es cluster has three pod.Now I have an index, from which I kept indexing and deleting documents(during this time, I tried to search a document such as [aaa] in kibana, [aaa] wasn't in search results), and after about 10 minutes, I set k8s cluster to insufficient cpu or memory state, and then the pods of es cluster terminated and restarted automatically(but they restarted failed because of insufficient memory), and a few minutes later, k8s recovered from insufficient memory state(during this time, I kept indexing and deleting documents),and es cluster recovered too, but then I searched [aaa] in kibana again, it was in search result. I have no idea about why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the cluster descended into a split-brain situation.

Consider this. You have all three pods up and running and they're all in the same service.

[ X X X ]

Everything is normal. You search for [aaa] and its not there.

> and then the pods of es cluster terminated and restarted automatically(but they restarted failed because of insufficient memory)

So it's quite possible at this point that your cluster went into split-brain where you actually have more than one ES cluster within those three pods. e.g.:

[ X Y Y ] where X is one cluster and Y is a second cluster

> (during this time, I kept indexing and deleting documents)

So it is possible that your indexing and deleting were being spread across the two clusters and not one, which would explain why you are seeing documents you thought you deleted.

You can see how many nodes your ES has by hitting `http://{eshost}:{esport}/_nodes`

If you see 1 or 2 nodes, you have a split-brain cluster, and will need to decide which way you want to merge the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I set k8s to insufficient state for twice. after first abnormal state, es cluster restarted and recovered normally, during this time, [aaa] can't be searched.But after second  abnormal state, es cluster restarted, but [aaa] appeared in searched result again. do you mean that more than one master of es cluster may cause this error? Thanks again~

Comment: No, when an ES pod starts, it tries to find a cluster master. If it does not find one, it will assume it is a new cluster. So it is possible that during startup one or more of your pods couldn't find a cluster master, assumed it was a new cluster, and set itself as master. Meaning within your three ES nodes you could have one, two, or three clusters.

Comment: But I checked the log, when es cluster was restarting, if there wasn't a master,  my indexing or deleting bulk requests failed with an error:Error 503 (Service Unavailable): blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];[type=cluster_block_exception], so I think if es cluster doesn't have a master, bulk requests will be rejected

Comment: Correct, so if you hit your service with the `_nodes` endpoint as in the answer, see if you have 1, 2 or 3 nodes showing up. If you have three pods but < 3 nodes in the output, you have a split brain'ed cluster

Comment: I did an experiment just now, when es cluster was in a normal state(node0 is the master), I indexed a document [aaa], then deleted it, then I searched for document [aaa], it wasn't in the result. Then I set k8s into a insufficient cpu and memory state,  es cluster was keeping restarting,  and a few minutes later,  I set k8s into normal state(during this time, I hit _cat/nodes, it returned node1 and node2, and a few minutes later, node0 added into cluster again), and es cluster recovered too(now the master is node1)., then I searched for document [aaa], it was in search result again

Comment: In between the cluster showing 2 nodes and 3 nodes, did you re-add the [aaa] back into the cluster?

Comment: No, I didn't re-add [aaa] into cluster, it can be searched again just after the es cluster recovered

Comment: Do your shards have replicas? e.g. `/_cat/shards` should show a "p" and "r" on different lines.

Comment: yes, this index was created with 6 primary shards and 6 replicas shards

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what happened. The behaviour you've described sounds like a split brain, but your results indicate no split brain. Can I check finally that you ARE using a statefulset setup with persistence?

Comment: yes, I use statefulset to setup the es cluster, and this is part of configuration of statefulset yaml:

Comment: Environment:
      node.name:                      (v1:metadata.name)
      cluster.initial_master_nodes:  es-master-0,es-master-1,es-master-2,
      discovery.seed_hosts:          es-master-headless
      cluster.name:                  es
      network.host:                  0.0.0.0
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:                  -Xmx1364m -Xms1364m
      node.data:                     true
      node.ingest:                   true
      node.master:                   true
      node.ml:                       true
      node.remote_cluster_client:    true

Comment: Mounts:
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml from esconfig (rw,path="elasticsearch.yml")
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from es-master (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data01 from host-path-01 (rw)

Comment: Volumes:
   esconfig:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      es-master-config
    Optional:  false
   host-path-01:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/elasticsearch/data01
    HostPathType:

Comment: Volume Claims:
  Name:          es-master
  StorageClass:  local-volume
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      1Gi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteOnce]

Comment: Did you use helm to apply your changes to the cpu/memory? If so, did you use the `--atomic` flag?

Comment: No，I didn't change the pod's cpu/memory, I just ran out of the virtual machines' cpu/memory, and then some pods of es cluster started to restart and kept restarting because of lacking of cpu/memory

Comment: By the way, I created this index with 30s refresh_interval, I have no idea that if it can cause this error

Comment: refresh_interval will affect how long changes take to show up in search (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_unset_or_increase_the_refresh_interval), so if you're searching for a doc you just deleted but within the 30secs you've set in your index, you will still find it because the cluster hasn't indexed that change yet.

Comment: I deleted document [aaa], and I confirmed it had been deleted by searching for it in kibana, then I set k8s to insufficient cpu/memory state, and after the es cluster recovered, [aaa] can be searched again.

Comment: Is the cluster being accessed by other services (e.g. is something else putting that [aaa] document back in after you've deleted it)

Comment: No, it was accessed by only one service, and these operations were operated according to same test cases.If I didn't set k8s to insufficient cpu/memory state, the result was correct.

Comment: hey，I found a setting of my index might cause this error, here is my setting:"index.translog.sync_interval": "10m",
  "index.translog.durability": "async", so when I deleted the document [aaa], it hadn't been flushed before the es cluster crashed, so when the cluster recovered, the data showed again, I'll confirm if it is the real reason